# If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, prove $f(A)-f(B)$ is subset of $f(A-B)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Question**: Let $$f:X\rightarrow Y.$$
If
$$A\subset X, B\subset\ X,$$
prove that $$f(A)-f(B)\subset f(A) - f(B).$$

**My Proof.** (Please check if this is correct. THANK YOU!)
Let
$$ b\in f(A)-f(B).$$
This means that
$$b\in f(A),$$
hence there is an $a$ such that $$a\in A,$$
and similarly since
$$b\not\in f(B),$$
then (is this conclusion correct?)$$a \not\in B.$$ 
Therefore we can say that
$$a\in A-B,$$
hence
$$b\in f(A-B),$$
hence
$$f(A)-f(B)\subset f(A-B).$$

Comment: You have a typo on line six. Other than that, the proof is fine.

Comment: I observe that $f(A)-f(B)=f(A)-f(B)$.  So, what you are trying to prove is trivially true. [edit: I now observe that your title is different from the body of the question itself.]

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the typo.

Comment: Your conclusion just before the 5th equation in your solution is right: The implication "$a\in B\Rightarrow f(a)\equiv b\in f(B)$" always holds, so its contrapositive "$b\not\in f(B)\Rightarrow a\not\in B$" also holds.

Comment: You should use \setminus ($A \setminus B$) rather than minus since the later is ambiguous.

Comment: Too glib.  Include b = f(a).